# Microsoft Access 2013 I made a form to input parameters for query but how do I then make a report from that query?

Tags: report, ms-access-2013

I made a form with a text box and list box that feed these inputs into the criteria section of my query. But once I make the query how can I set it up so I can make a report from that query without having to create a report from scratch every time. 
P.S. I had to use the form to make the query and could not have the query pop up a parameter box before running because of a lookup table issue.

Answer (score 0):

Build the report and then in the record source area of the report, which looks like building a regular query, use the field values from the form.  ie right click the criteria area and choose build, in the dropdowns on the left you should see the form and the form fields.